# How to functionally convert a nested hash to a list of records?

Tags: functional-programming, raku

Let's say I have a nested hash describing money quantities:

```
my %money = (coins => {'50c' => 4}, notes => {'10' => 1, '20' => 5});
```

My desired format is a record list:

```
my @money = [
  (:type('coins'), :subtype('50c'), value => 4),
  (:type('notes'), :subtype('10'), value => 1),
  (:type('notes'), :subtype('20'), value => 5),
];
```

The most obvious answer is loops:

```
my @money;
for %money.kv -> $type, %sub-records {
  for %sub-records.kv -> $subtype, $value {
    @money.push: (:$type, :$subtype, :$value);
  }
}
```

But I'm allergic to separating a variable from the code that populates it. Next, I tried to create the variable with functional transformations on the input hash:

```
%money.kv.map: -> $k1, %hsh2 { :type($k1) X, %hsh2.kv.map(->$k2, $v2 {:subtype($k2), :$v2, :value($v2)}) }
```

But I didn't get the nesting right. I want a list of flat lists. Plus, the above is a mess to read.

The compromise is the `gather`/`take` construct which lets me construct a list by iteration without any temporary/uninitialized junk in the main scope:

```
my @money = gather for %money.kv -> $type, %sub-records {
  for %sub-records.kv -> $subtype, $value {
    take (:$type, :$subtype, :$value);
  }
};
```

But I'm curious, what is the right way to get this right with just list transformations like `map`, `X` or `Z`, and `flat`? ("key1", "key2", and "value" are fine field names, since an algorithm shouldn't be domain specific.)

Edit: I should mention that in Perl 6, `gather`/`take` is the most readable solution (best for code that's not write-only). I'm still curious about the pure functional solution.

Comment: I think this is a good use of `gather`/`take`

Comment: @BradGilbert I do too, since it's probably the most readable solution, but I'm curious about the pure functional way. I'm reading your answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl6
my @money = %money.map:
-> ( :key($type), :value(%records) ) {
  slip

      :$type xx *
    Z
      ( 'subtype' X=> %records.keys   )
    Z
      (   'value' X=> %records.values )
}
```

You could do `.kv.map: -> $type, %records {…}`

---

- `-> ( :key($type), :value(%records) ) {…}` destructures a Pair object
- `:$type` creates a `type => $type` Pair
- `:$type xx *` repeats `:$type` infinitely (`Z` stops when any of it's inputs stops)
- `('subtype' X=> %records.keys)` creates a list of Pairs
  (Note that `.keys` and `.values` are in the same order if you don't modify the Hash between the calls)
- `Z` zips two lists
- `slip` causes the elements of the sequence to slip into the outer sequence
  (`flat` would flatten too much)

---

If you wanted them to be sorted

```perl6
my @money = %money.sort.map: # 'coins' sorts before 'notes'
-> ( :key($type), :value(%records) ) {

  # sort by the numeric part of the key
  my @sorted = %records.sort( +*.key.match(/^\d+/) );

  slip

      :$type xx *
    Z
      ( 'subtype' X=> @sorted».key   )
    Z
      (   'value' X=> @sorted».value )
}
```

You could do `.sort».kv.map: -> ($type, %records) {…}`

Comment: Thanks! Using an infinite list and that first `Z` really makes it simpler. (`X` would work instead, but that creates another layer of nesting and needs to be removed with another `slip`.)